# Why is my TcpSocket receiving exactly the same data?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to send one value to multiple TcpSockets but every client gets an own value.

I have a variable called clientCounter, the clientCounter has the number of clients which are connected. The server sends to all clients the number of clients which are connected. When one is connected 1 is sent to all clients.

Now the results: For example when 4 clients are connected, Client1 receives the number 1, Client2 the number 2, etc...

But the results should be: Every client should get the number 4 when for example four clients are connected.

Main thread:

```cpp
int main(){
    Server server;

    while (true) {
        server.Send(server.GetPlayerCount());
    }

        return 0;
}
```

The number of clients are stored in there:

```cpp
std::atomic<unsigned int> clientCounter;
```

```cpp
int Server::GetPlayerCount()
{
    return clientCounter;
}
```

This shows the function which is sending the data to all clients:

```cpp
void Server::Send(int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < clientCounter; i++) {
        sf::Packet packet;
        packet << m;


        if (clients[i].send(packet) != sf::Socket::Status::Done) {
            std::cout << "Cant send Packet" << std::endl;
        }

        packet.clear();
    }
}
```

This is what the client is doing:

```cpp
    sf::Packet packet;
    int count = 0;

    while (true) {
        socket.receive(packet);
        packet >> count;
        std::cout << count << std::endl;
    }
```

When client is connected, clientCounter add one:

```cpp
        if (listener.accept(clients[clientCounter]) != sf::Socket::Status::Done) {
            std::cout << "Error cant get Socket..." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "New client connected: " << clients[clientCounter].getRemoteAddress() << std::endl;
            clientCounter++;
        }
```

And I want that all clients get all the same number.

Comment: I don't see `clientCounter` ever being modified in your code.

Comment: What is the problem you have now? What happens when the client and server connects? What is supposed to happen? What is sent, and what is received? What is *supposed* to be sent, and what is supposed to be received? And please try to create a [mcve] to show us, of both the client and server (and don't forget the *minimal* part).

Comment: @freakish I added it now in the post at the end. A simple ```clientCounter++``` when client is connected.

Comment: I can't really follow your question. Please be as clear as possible.

Comment: I have a variable called clientCounter, the clientCounter has the number of clients which are connected. The server sends to all clients the number of clients which are connected. When one is connected 1 is sent to all clients. 

Now the results: For example when 4 clients are connected, Client1 receives the number 1, Client2 the number 2, etc...

But the results should be: Every client should get the number 4 when for example four clients are connected.